# Magento Module Custom Grid Not working

Tags: magento, grid

Hi i am working on one module which collects data from custom table and display in grid in grid user can add and edit content. but that module working fine offline ( MAMP ) but when i pull to magento online ( linux ) then stops working.
here is screenshot :
From Linux : [image]

[image]

Offline shows everything fine and cool :

if someone has any idea please ping me.

according to me. code not calling :

_prepareCollection

_prepareColumns

because i add some echo in files that that's showing but in these functions echo text not showing please take a look on screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your module is working perfectly fine in your local machine but creating issues on actual server, please check your file permissions and folder structure of migrated module.

Many times it happens due to file permissions.

Comment: thanks for answer how i can reset permissions i means is there any way to reset automatically. i saw my files permissions are 755.. and i saw some other modules files permissions 644 so do i need to change files permissions to 644

Comment: thanks it was permissions error i manually change every file permission to 644 and folder to 755 under my custom module and then i disable module from backend then reenable then flush cache then starts working.. thanks for help..

Comment: Awesome. Glad i cud help :)